# Installing Sql server 2016 doesn't add sql services

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I install sql server 2016, sql server 2016 sp1 and it's ssms. but I cant to connect local server. I check services.msc but it contains no sql services like sql server agent , ...

Comment: Did you change the instance name from the default?  Also, if you do not see the services, then something did not install correctly.  Reinstall/repair the installation.

Comment: no I didn't change default instance name, I repair it, every thing were success.

Comment: Restart the computer?

Comment: yes , I did. it doesn't work

Comment: What is your host OS?

Comment: I Install it on my pc , my os is windows 10

Comment: Assuming you are not running Windows 10 Home and have the latest build (1703) I cannot come up with any reason why SQL would not install.  If you try to connect, what error do you get?

Comment: I have win 10 Enterprise (1607 build number). when i try to connect to local, I get ' a network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to Sql server...'

Comment: Right, 2 things.  1) Did you change the port for SQL?  The default is 1433  2) Did you setup the Windows Firewall Rule?  Setup should have warned you about this and usually if you are running local, I do not think it usually matters but better to be safe.

Comment: I'm trying to connect it via SSMS, with no port number and firewall checking. I think main problem is that necessary services don't run, and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Check Windows event log, any error there? Check installation log at C:\programfiles\ Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log\. Check sql server configuration manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It solved by three steps :

1.Update Visual Studio Installer

2.Update Visual Studio(from VS 2017 build 15.0.0 to build 15.3.0)

3.Repair SQL Server again.

Services added correctly, every thing is fine now.